# how to catch silverlight crash

Tags: silverlight, crash

I have a strange bug. I'm developing a silverlight application and on a specific server, the silverlight crashes. It happens when I scroll the page or expand a tree, etc. This happens randomly, but in the end it will crash.

How can I catch and investigate that crash?

Unfortunately this behavior is not reproducible in developer environment.

Thnx, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.UnhandledException` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
BTW, your crash looks similar "Runtime Error 4008... Layout Cycle Detected... Layout Could Not Complete."